# smf player timeline property

Tags: javascript, silverlight-4.0, mmppf

Hi I am using silverlight player with smf framework with C#.

REF: http://smf.codeplex.com/

**I am trying to get the position where video had been paused at**. Since I am new to this I think I am not doing it correctly. In my JavaScript I have this funcion

```
 function Pause() {

                    Player.Pause();
                    alert(Player.Timeline.LivePosition());


            }
```

it pauses the video but then alerts this

```
Error: Object does not support this property or method
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong property, as you might have guessed. LivePosition is for live streaming (think web TV / broadcast).

The position in a regular video is PlaybackPosition. It's a property from SMFPlayer too.

I'm using it in C#, I don't know how it works in the Javascript bridge though.